# How to determine which database is selected

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to later output the name of the database that is currently selected?

Answer (score 458, accepted):

Just use mysql_query (or mysqli_query, even better, or use PDO, best of all) with:

```sql
SELECT DATABASE();
```

---

### Addendum:

There is much discussion over whether or not `FROM DUAL` should be included in this or not. On a technical level, it is a holdover from Oracle and can safely be removed. If you are inclined, you can use it as follows:

```sql
SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL;
```

That said, it is perhaps important to note, that while `FROM DUAL` does not actually *do* anything, it is valid MySQL syntax. From a strict perspective, including braces in a single line conditional in JavaScript also does not *do anything*, but it is still a valid practice.

Comment: DUAL is an Oracle table, that was taken over into MySQL. It's a dummy table for operations that do not require an actual table. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table

Comment: @DigitalPrecision It is a holdover from the fact that I've done a lot of work with Oracle. Oracle does not allow you to select unless it is *from* something, so there is a special table called "DUAL" which has only one cell in it. You can omit it.

Comment: Probably should edit this keeping the existing answer for posterity but adding `SELECT DATABASE();` as the "actual" answer.

Comment: @JanThomä so that mean I can perform any query on DUAL table ?

Comment: @PardeepJain that is outside my area of expertise maybe cwallenpoole can answer that.

Comment: @PardeepJain You should probably make that into a separate question.

Comment: You know, I've been working with different databases for 15 years now, and it STILL makes me feel better to be able to select "from" something, even when I'm just calling a stored procedure. The last few years has been in PostgreSQL and I find myself wishing I could `SELECT current_database() FROM DUAL`.

Answer (score 130):

```
SELECT DATABASE();
```

p.s. I didn't want to take the liberty of modifying @cwallenpoole's answer to reflect the fact that this is a MySQL question and not an Oracle question and doesn't need `DUAL`.

Comment: Old habits die hard. I *still* sometimes think "FROM DUAL" even though I haven't touched Oracle since 2011.

Comment: Yep. Still thinking *FROM DUAL* even though I haven't touched Oracle since 2011.

Comment: This is me again… Still thinking it.

Comment: @cwallenpoole are you still thinking it?

Comment: @Farhan.K Yes. In all fairness, I think it's one of the few things Oracle did better syntactically than the other RDMS.

Comment: @cwallenpoole how about now?

Comment: upvote if you love the chain of "still thinking it?" comments :) I'm still thinking it. I love that mysql supports it either way.

Comment: @cwallenpoole still thinking it? I need to know!!

Comment: @OneCoolBoi Less now. I'm working in PostgreSQL and the DUAL pseudo-table doesn't exist there. But there are times when I'm calling a function and I get the nasty feeling, "Damn it, I should be selecting FROM something."

Comment: I've had to use oracle recently, having come from a postgres background, "FROM DUAL" just seems so bizarre.

Comment: Sorry to bother you @cwallenpoole, I was just wondering if you're still thinking it... curious to know!

Comment: @DavidRefoua After 3 years with PgSQL, I don't really think about it as much, but a SELECT without a FROM still feels a little naked.

Answer (score 71):

You can always use STATUS command to get to know **Current database & Current User**

[image]

Comment: although not reflected in the output above, on my system, it also shows the TCP port, which is handy for me since I'm running mysqld_multi and I like to remind myself which instance I'm talking to.

Answer (score 6):

slightly off-topic (using the CLI instead of PHP), but still worth knowing:
You can set the prompt to display the default database by using any of the following

```
mysql --prompt='\d> '
export MYSQL_PS1='\d> '
```

or once inside

```
prompt \d>\_
\R \d>\_
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way for filtering the database with specific word.

```
SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` LIKE '<yourDatabasePrefixHere>%'
or
SHOW DATABASES LIKE '<yourDatabasePrefixHere>%';
```

**Example:**

```
SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` LIKE 'foobar%'
foobar_animal
foobar_humans_gender
foobar_objects
```

Comment: Question is to show which is the currently selected database, however your reply is showing procedure to filter database.

Correct way is to run: SELECT DATABASE();

Comment: I think you missed the intro text 'Another way...' The Accepted answer already mentioned `SELECT DATABASE();`.