# How to determine which MySQL database has been selected?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL: determine which database is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096550/mysql-determine-which-database-is-selected)

I'm trying to debug some problems with a project from someone else. It looks like I get data from an other database, but I'm connected to the right one.  So I thought, let's look at what database I'm connected to.

How can I look at what database I'm connected at runtime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run the following query:

```
SELECT DATABASE();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`mysql_get_host_info();`](http://php.net/mysql_get_host_info).
This will return the hostname of the server you are connected to.

You also have [`mysql_get_server_info()`](http://php.net/mysql_get_server_info) and [`mysql_get_proto_info()`](http://php.net/mysql_get_proto_info) which will return the server version number and communication protocol version number respectively.

Comment: None of this information will help determine which database is selected.  It only gives information about the MySQL server itself.

Comment: Given that your request was "what database your are CONNECTED to" I naturally assumed you meant network connection. To determine with database is SELECTED use SELECT DATABASE()

Answer (score -3):

Use [`mysql_db_name()`](http://php.net/mysql_db_name).

Comment: `mysql_list_dbs()` is deprecated in 5.4.  Since this function relies on that you should not use this to determine the currently selected database.

Comment: You can't find out the currently selected database with this anyway, since [`mysql_list_dbs()`](http://php.net/mysql_list_dbs) does nothing but list all the available databases.

Comment: I posed the link to the function 'mysql_db_name()', I don't know why is that problem??

Comment: @luka, the only problem is that it does nothing to answer the OP's question.