# MySql - Use database name in column alias

Tags: mysql

I am working with several databases, and in order to avoid mistakes I would like to add to the column name the database name.

For example, for the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM users;
```

I would like to have something like this as a result:

```
+-----------------+
| total IN dbName |  <-- dynamic alias
+-----------------+
|          344320 |
+-----------------+
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8096574/1039488) I have the DB name with this query:

```
SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL;
```

But unfortunately it looks like MySql does not like having a dynamic `AS`.
I tried these queries, all of them raise an error:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CONCAT('total', ' IN ', SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL) FROM my_table;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS (SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL) FROM my_table;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS CONCAT('total', ' IN ', ' xxx') FROM my_table;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Output column alias cannot be parametrized. Use dynamic SQL.

Comment: A table alias can be referenced `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses. Hence, having a dynamic alias would require to execute some part of the query while parsing the query itself.

Answer (score 3):

As @Akina mention, looks like it is impossible to have a dynamic alias.
Instead, I found this solution, I leave it here in case it might help somebody:

```
SET @db_name := (SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL);
SET @query := CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total IN ', @db_name, '` FROM my_table');
PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
```